# docker push to dockerhub private repo sometimes pushes existing layer again (ubuntu base layer)

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am pushing to dockerhub. I thought every time I push it should be incremental. But sometimes it pushes existing layer again.

here is few pushes in time order

```
// n-th push
1515e3a2aade: Layer already exists 
fbe2db54eaea: Layer already exists 
b3194de9c939: Layer already exists 
abf060fbeb02: Layer already exists 
bc61dcaa1fb9: Layer already exists 
629d3660cc59: Pushed 
5f70bf18a086: Pushed 
0d81735d8272: Pushed 
982549bd6b32: Pushed 
8698b31c92d5: Pushed

// n+1-th push
5a2c20b22bf1: Pushed 
43ba1325889f: Pushed 
c23b65a5145c: Pushed 
abf060fbeb02: Layer already exists 
bc61dcaa1fb9: Layer already exists 
629d3660cc59: Layer already exists 
5f70bf18a086: Layer already exists 
0d81735d8272: Layer already exists 
982549bd6b32: Layer already exists 
8698b31c92d5: Layer already exists

// n+2-th push, notice how layer 8698b31c92d5 and 3 more layers got pushed again
06db42d823c5: Pushed 
a3575dd784b5: Pushed 
e04cb41bff92: Pushed 
abf060fbeb02: Layer already exists 
bc61dcaa1fb9: Layer already exists 
629d3660cc59: Pushed 
5f70bf18a086: Layer already exists 
0d81735d8272: Pushed 
982549bd6b32: Pushed 
8698b31c92d5: Pushed
```

and here is docker history of n+2-th push

```
54ee4d70917c        10 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 12000/tcp 12001/tcp    0 B                 
8ae93e68a93a        10 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT &{["./nexus"]}     0 B                 
7644eba33444        10 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY multi:609730bd4dcd2093   571 kB              
ac87f067a414        10 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY multi:7b816c50da4eff99   10.84 MB            
52ad31e3d4fb        10 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:dc5824a16ae1ce7e8   14.9 MB             
841eb28ef938        44 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /prod/bin             0 B                 
b167f0cca892        44 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /prod/socketio/asset/       0 B                 
c9c427a1999d        44 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /prod/eval/bin              0 B                 
9bad1ce6d92c        44 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /prod/bin                   0 B                 
3876b81b5a81        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/   1.895 kB            
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/polic   194.5 kB            
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:7ce20ce3daa6af21db   187.7 MB
```

Any idea why layer `<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:7ce20ce3daa6af21db   187.7 MB`(8698b31c92d5) get pushed again?

Edit: I restarted docker host (docker-machine restart default), does that matter? Shouldn't docker push get a list of existing layer hash from server before pushing?

Comment: not sure if it has anything to do with it but, are you using the `latest` tag on your base image? is that base image being updated on its own?

Comment: @saljuama yes I am using latest tag. The base image has the same hash every time, so I assume it's not updated.